# Google Sheets latest past Friday / week Forex closing price

Tags: google-sheets

I need the closing price for a currency pair for the latest past Friday, or one can say last week's closing price.

Currently I'm using this formula, but it's incorrect:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A3, "close", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -6)), 2, 2)
```

A3 is the currency pair for example AUDUSD.

Thus, this week, does not matter the day, it should give the closing price for last week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=googlefinance("CURRENCY:AUDUSD", "close", floor(today(),7)-1)
```

- *it will show `past friday` even on **current_friday** & `current_friday` will reflect from **saturday***

[image]